# Issue with presentPopoverFromRect and setPopoverContentSize in iOS7

Tags: ipad, ios7, uipopovercontroller, popover

To get popovers in iOS7 to function properly it appears I have to make some workarounds, in the code below I'm trying to understand why redisplaying the popover the second time is necessary. Without the redisplay when in iOS7 the arrows point to the wrong place if they are turned on. Normally the app runs in landscape so I'm wondering if that has to do with orientation and timing of the animations. Also without the redisplay a transparent pane zooms out in about 500ms to fill the screen just before the popover slides into place. With the redisplay then the popover just snaps into the right place, as expected.

```
NSArray *currSysVer= [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if(self.showingKeyboard == NO) {
    if([[currSysVer objectAtIndex:0] intValue] > 6)
    {
        [selectPopover  presentPopoverFromRect:localField.frame inView:localField permittedArrowDirections:NO animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [selectPopover  presentPopoverFromRect:localField.frame inView:localField permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}

//Determine height and width of popover to fit all values
CGFloat width = 320;

if(multiSelect) {
    width = 450;
}

for(NSString *value in values) {

    CGSize size = [value sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:23]];

    if(size.width > width) {
        width = size.width;
    }
}

CGFloat height = (44 * [values count] + 1) > 800 ? 800 : 44 * [values count] + 1;

if([[currSysVer objectAtIndex:0] intValue] > 6) {
    height += 6;
}

[selectPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height + 36) animated:NO];

if(self.showingKeyboard == NO && [[currSysVer objectAtIndex:0] intValue] > 6) {
    [selectPopover  presentPopoverFromRect:localField.frame inView:localField permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Same issue: in iOS6 the position is right. IN iOS7 not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and can't really find a solution nor the reason. Maybe it's a bug, maybe not. Because for me it didnt matter too much if i presented popover horizontally or vertically, i used this workaround:

```
permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown)
```

This way the popover wasnt floating around, and pointed to the right position.

Hope this helps to some.

Comment: I also tried that but I have lots of different anchors in our app, and was finding that although it improved where the arrows pointed on many of the fields, it didn't do all, nor did it address the other issues. However I'm sure your answer may help some people. It certainly seems like a tidier fix than mine does at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really struggling to understand why you're calling **presentPopoverFromRect:** before you call **setPopoverContentSize:**.  I'm using **UIPopoverController** in my app, and I always set the content size before I display the popover.

Have you tried modifying your code so that you calculate the proper size for your popover - and then call **setPopoverContentSize:** - before you call **presentPopoverFromRect:**?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, didn't work. I was very new to iOS dev at the time I posted this question, although I've been a dotNet dev for many years. I'm still not quite clear on why or how my code above fixed my issue (double presentation of popover). I posted this question in an effort to understand what was happening. Hate fixing things by accident lol.